Reflected light sensor with kazev6
I have a problem when programming the sensor to use the "reflected light" mode, in the Kazi Code program, I can't use its commands to change the way I use the reflected light mode.
import rcu
import time

def task1() : 
    rcu.SetLightSensorLed(6,1)
    while True :
        rcu.SetDisplayVar(1,1,rcu.GetLightSensor(6),63488,0)
        time.sleep(1)
    

task1()

Try this code above, but it doesn't match the correct reading values ​​and I can't use the wrong reading of it to execute any commands. I would like an example for the correct functioning of the sensor of the EV6 kazi robot model.
